Can we burn [record]?
I found the record tag. I showed it used a the record keyword in Java. While trying to see others posts, I see it has multiples used as record for database, record for phone, or an object.
Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
No. It has multiple meaning, and it should be with another tag to may be understandable. For example, a post with java and record should be about the keyword in Java.
Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
Yes, as it's a general concept.
Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
No. Some other tag are more relevant for this meaning:

mediarecorder for recording audio on Android
audio-recording for recording audio in general
recordset for database related (could also be row, rows or struct)
java-record for Java keyword

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
No.
I think this tag should be removed.

Why "Resolve ambiguity with the [record] tag?" post is used as duplicate as it's old and without any answer? While the second is directly linked with my post, the first one ask for something different

Well let's zoom out. It's been covered twice before at least, and yet here we are. Still in the same boat. Are we expecting this time to be any different? And secondly, lets take note of the fact that it is actually possible on meta to dupe close to a question without an answer, something not allowed on the main site. So that should imply that dupe voting works differently on meta. That being said... I don't really know what we gain from this being closed. Like so many other meta posts it should be free to collect 2 or 3 upvotes and then just collect dust.
